# Use python to reproduce bash command 'ls -a' output

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am new to python and am working on writing bash `ls` command in python, I am stuck on `ls -a` option which (according to the manpage):

> Include directory entries whose names begin with a dot (`.')

I am aware of os.listdir() but it does not list special entries '.' and '..'

> From the docs: os.listdir(path):
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

I need help in listing these special entries through python, I would appreciate if someone can help me out here a little.

Thanks all for your patience.

Comment: yeah thats a option, thanks for the input

Comment: So is there no way to get these special entries through python?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. You can use the constants `os.curdir` and `os.pardir` to get the names of these special directories, instead of hard-coding them.

Comment: don't forget to exclude entries that start with a dot if `-a` is not given e.g., `result = [e for e in os.listdir(path) if not e.startswith('.')]`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yeah, I was struggling with `ls -a` option special entries only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add them manually to `os.listdir()` result. `result = [os.curdir, os.pardir] + os.listdir(path)`.

Most modern filesystems no longer create the actual hardlinks but all APIs include the names explicitly anyway.

Comment: @user596374: don't mix Unicode and bytestrings. You could use `curdir = lambda path: fsdecode(os.curdir) if isinstance(path, unicode) else os.curdir`